# How do I animate a view when presenting a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom `alert` which is presented as a `UIView` on a `UIViewController`. So when I want to present the `alert` I `present` the `UIViewController` which brings up the `alert`. The problem that I'm having is that I want to do a simple animation on the `alert` when it's shown. But as it is presented as a `UIViewController` and not just shown with a `UIView` overlay, I'm a bit confused as how to accomplish this. Here's the relevant code:

```
static func standardMessageAlert(title: String, msg: String, action: ((_ text: String?) -> Void)? = nil) -> CustomAlertViewController? {
    let alert = CustomAlertViewController.create(title: title, message: msg)
        
    let okAction = CustomAlertAction(title: "OK", type: .normal, handler: action)

    alert?.addAction(okAction)
         
    return alert
}
```

And the code for `CustomAlertViewController`, which is pretty big, but the create method looks like this:

```
static func create(title: String?, message: String?, addon: Addon? = nil, alertType: AlertType? = nil) -> CustomAlertViewController? {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Overlay", bundle: nil)
    guard let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomAlertViewController") as? CustomAlertViewController else {
            return nil
        }
        
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    viewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        
    viewController.alertType = alertType
    viewController.addon = addon
    viewController.alertTitle = title
    viewController.alertMessage = message
        
    return viewController
    }
...
```

The `alert` is presented like this:

```
func present(animated: Bool, onView: UIViewController? = UIApplication.rootViewController(), completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    onView?.present(self, animated: animated, completion: nil)
}
```

The animation would be something basic like this:

```
func animateView() {
    alertView.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { [weak self] () -> Void in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.alertView.alpha = 1.0
    })
}
```

`alertView` is the `outlet` for the `alert` `UIView` that is inside the `UIViewController`. I guess this is what I should animate, but where do I put that code? How do I implement it when the `UIViewController` is presented? I have also tried using `onView.view` to animate it. The problem that I see is that if I put the animation code before `presenting` it's too early, and if it's after presenting then its too late.

Comment: have you tried setting the background color opacity of view to 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep this logic then I can suggest you to setup initial view state in `viewDidLoad` and run animation after `viewWillAppear`.
But I recommend to use [custom transitions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/animation_and_haptics/view_controller_transitions)